# I need to add a new column in the table in SQL

Tags: sql

i have a table with below data

```
Account Name tripdate

123     sam  02/20/13

234     sim  02/20/14
```

My query is

```
SELECT *, 

(CASE 
    WHEN (DATENAME(dw, [tripdate]) ='Sunday') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS [Sunday],

(CASE 
    WHEN (DATENAME(dw, [tripdate]) ='Monday') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS [Monday],

(CASE 
    WHEN (DATENAME(dw, [tripdate]) ='Tuesday') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS [Tuesday],

(CASE 
    WHEN (DATENAME(dw, [Starting Date of Trip]) ='Wednesday') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS [Wednesday],

(CASE 
    WHEN (DATENAME(dw, [Starting Date of Trip]) ='Thursday') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS [Thursday],

(CASE 
    WHEN (DATENAME(dw, [tripdate]) ='Friday') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS [Friday],

(CASE 
    WHEN (DATENAME(dw, [tripdate]) ='Saturday') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) AS [Saturday]
FROM [Table]   GROUP BY [ Account]
```

and the output is

```
Account Name tripdate sunday monday tuesday  Dayname

123     sam  02/20/13  1       0       0     sunday

234     sim  02/20/14  0       0       1     tuesday
```

Now i need help in getting the last column dayname.

Comment: Seems like the answer is in the question. What's wrong with `DATENAME(dw, [tripdate])` ?

Comment: what you mean by `last column dayname` ?

Answer (score 0):

just use....

```
DATENAME(dw, [tripdate]) as dayname
```

Comment: Account Name sunday monday tuesday  Dayname

123     sam    1       0       0     sunday

234     sim    0       2       1     Monday

Comment: i grouped by the account number. so the Dayname column should specify the max day name of all the columns....

Comment: @user3757032 Ok, you grouped. What does the dayname represent then ? First day, last day ? Please add specific information in your question.